# Whose voice is it when you do the ubuntu sound test?

Tags: 14.04, sound

When I go on the sound settings in Ubuntu, I can test my stereo speakers and there is a voice which says "Front left" and "Front right". I was curious today on whether this is Ubuntu's text-to-speech or is it a pre-recorded voice? If it was a pre-recorded voice, whose voice is it?

Comment: My guess is: a syntesized voice ((but not Ubuntu's text-to-speech). :)

Comment: If an actual person spoke those then those phrases are likely from  stock production music. So no names involved, just a free to use cd or dvd with generic phrases.